# help with textgreek package

Tags: errors, memoir

I can't seem to get textgreek to work on my system and I am out of ideas where to try next to fix it.

I'm using LyX to write my thesis, so the TeX output is autogenerated. That said, I am perfectly comfortable with the raw text.

The following document fails and I really don't understand the error message, as I have been fortunate to have LaTeX 'just work' pretty much so far.

```
%% LyX 2.0.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,english,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{textgreek}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
This is a new doc

\textDelta \textbeta
\end{document}
```

Not so helpful help message:

```
     \textDelta
               \textbeta
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

Error message:

! Font LGR/cmr/m/n/10=grmn1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

For the record, I am using MikTex2.9 on Windows 7

Comment: That's not actually the error message but its (not so helpful) help text. The error message should be just before that something like `Font \jgjhg=cmhjhsgds  not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.` If that is the error message then most likely you have the latex package for greek but not the fonts,

Comment: Thanks @David. Is now updated, so how do I install the fonts using Miktex on Windows?

Comment: I don't use miktex, and I'm just going offline, but someone here should be able to help now you've narrowed down the cause.

Comment: Found that the fonts exist in a package called cbgreek which could be installed from the package manager. It all works. So thanks for the pointer! It was all I needed

Comment: In order to avoid "random" errors like this, the best is to install every package and forget about it.

Comment: Too bad this is closed. I have a similar problem, and no clue where to start. Even if very specific, it would give me pointer where to start looking... :(

Comment: Did you check the cbgreek package fonts?

Comment: I have a very similar situation for cyrillic, so it may be a general question on how to install esotic fonts. I would suggests to reopen.
(even for just greek, it may be of interest for whoever needs to write a greek word, say from Plato.)